# Angular Bootstrap Navigation unable to switch between nav-tabs

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap [navigation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navs/)  in angular application as shown in below HTML

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="test-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" routerLink="/test" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " id="viral-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" routerLink="/viral"  role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Viral</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="user-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" routerLink="/user/{{username}}" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">User</a>
    </li>
   
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="test" role="tabpanel"  aria-labelledby="test-tab">
    
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="viral" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="viral-tab"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="user" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="user-tab">
       
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

I'm not able to switch between different nav tabs , it is always the `"test-tab"`which is active.
How can I switch between different nav-tabs.?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use routerLinkActive for setting the active class.
I have modified your code and removed href attribute since it can cause trouble when not used for navigating.

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="test-tab" data-toggle="tab" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/test"  role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " id="viral-tab" data-toggle="tab" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/viral"  role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Viral</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="user-tab" data-toggle="tab" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/user/{{username}}" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">User</a>
    </li>
   
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="test" role="tabpanel"  aria-labelledby="test-tab">
    
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="viral" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="viral-tab"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="user" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="user-tab">
       
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have changed to 'routerLinkActive' still the same , only one tab is active and not others are not clickable

Comment: Have you removed the href attribute as well?
And have you configured the routes in angular?

Comment: yes href attribute is removed completely and routes are already present in the application, trying to fit the navigation bar  and the nav tabs are not clickable

Comment: The element can still be clickable even if the cursor is not showing the pointer. What happens in the console log when clicking the button?

Comment: no console log captured, I have written (click) method to log the event but nothing captured